# What is the Use Case of `extrapolate` in `Akka-Streams`?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I just tried `conflate` and `extrapolate` in `akka-streams`.

As `conflate` makes totally sense to me, I don't get the Use Case of `extrapolate`.

Why should we add more work for the downstream - when the upstream does not demand it?

From the Scala Doc:

> Allows a faster downstream to progress independent of a slower upstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one example:

### Game development

In video games, it's common to have at least two "loops": a logic/game loop and a rendering loop. Usually, the rate of the game loop (the "tick rate") is slower than the rate of the rendering loop (the "frame rate"). For example, a logic tick might occur 10 times a second, but the frame rate should usually be at least 60 frames per second. In order for there to be something to render in between ticks, game developers use either [extrapolation or interpolation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/118006/when-should-i-extrapolate-and-when-should-i-interpolate/118007). As you might have guessed, the extrapolate function is well suited for extrapolation. Here's an example with a tick rate of 10 ticks per second and no frame rate limit:

```
Source.tick(0.millis, 100.millis, 0)
    .scan(intialGameState) { (g, _) => tick(g) }
    .extrapolate(extrapolateFn)
    .runForeach(render)
```

Now `extrapolateFn` just needs to return an iterator that provides extrapolated game states on demand:

```
def extrapolateFn(g: GameState) = Iterator.continually {
  // Compute how long it has been since `g` was created
  // Advance the state by that amount of time
  // Return the new state
}
```